# AngularJS: Filtering not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, loops, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` defined as so:

```
{"ng-repeat" => "city in cities() | filter: search"}
```

A city is `{ attributes: {name: 'Boston'} }`

And a form like so:

```
%input{:type => "search", "ng-model" => "search.attributes.name"}
```

But it's not working, how can I filter based on `city.attributes.name` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your filter term should be like:

`city in cities() | filter: {attributes: {name: search}}`

And then set your model to the value of search:

`%input{:type => "search", "ng-model" => "search"}`